# Set maximum label width using the minimum amount of lines

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

Hi I'm facing this issue:

I am trying to achieve this:

I want that the red label doesn't use more than the 50% of the cell width, but if it needs less space or it is a multiline calculate the real width of the cell instead of leaving a big blank space where there is no text.

[image: Goal]

What I am getting:

If I force it to be 50% of the width:

[image: Wrong experiment]

If I set width equals or less than 50% of the width:

[image]
[image]

Comment: all you need is to set label width half of cell width ?

Comment: No because if I set the label width to the half of the cell, the 2 icons are too separate from the text, and also if the text is shorter and only needs 1 line it would take the half anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! To make that a multiline label gets the real width instead of the maximum with but using the minimum amount of lines like this:

[image: Goal]

instead of this:

[image: Not desired]

You have to set the **horizontal compression resistance priority** to 1000.

[image: how to do it]